# How to find multiplicity of eigenvalues?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus, diagonalization

So i have this matrix:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brgsn.png)

Sorry for the formatting, I'm new here and any help would be great.

We compute the characteristic polynomial

$p(\lambda)= {\rm det}(A − \lambda I d)= (\lambda + 2)^2 (1 − λ)$

So from here I know that one of the root is 1 and the other one is -2. However, it states on the answer sheet that the multiplicity of -2 is 2 ? How come ? I don't see two -2 roots in the equation .

Somebody please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of your characteristic equation as:

$$p(\lambda) = (\lambda + 2)(\lambda + 2)(1 - \lambda)$$

to see the multiplicity of eigenvalues better.

Comment: So i would need to look at (λ + 2)² as it if were two distinct equations?

Comment: No... having two (equal) *solutions*.

Comment: I don't understand ; i meant i need to see (λ + 2)² as two different brackets as you said

Comment: Are you unfamiliar with the fact that $(\lambda + 2)^2 = (\lambda +2)(\lambda + 2)$?????